# I am teaching him English

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, syntax, present-participles

> I **teach** him English.
>
> I **teaching** him English.
>
> I **am teaching** him English.

Are these sentences above grammatically correct?

Comment: MartinW is correct. But I just want to add a little bit, the second example is ungrammatical because a progressive aspect should be marked by a form of BE. "I **am** teaching.."

Comment: In these sentences, teaching, is an active/present participle, not a gerund. An example of a gerund would be **teaching is fun**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is Present Simple. It's used for routines, schedules, general truths, etc. in the present; and for scheduled future events.

> I teach him English every day.
>
> Water boils at 100 degrees Celsius.
>
> The train departs at 11:30 p.m.

The second one is not correct.

The third one is Present Continuous. It's used for things happening now.

> I am now teaching him English.